# symfony 3 doctrine does not accept primary key

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm

I am new to Symfony and trying to setup entities and relationships. Even though I seemed to have correctly annotated the primary keys.

When running

> php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate

I got an error as follows:

> The referenced column name 'brandId' has to be a primary key column on the target entity class 'AppBundle\Entity\Brands'.

The entities look like ( only relevant portions):

Thanks

Brands

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="brands")
 */
class Brands
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="smallint",length=3,unique=true,options={"unsigned":true})
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $brandId;

/**
 * one brands has many models
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Models", mappedBy="brandId")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="brandId", referencedColumnName="brandId")
 */
private $models;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->models = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Models:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ModelsRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="models")
 */
class Models
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="smallint",length=4,unique=true,options={"unsigned":true})
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $modelId;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25)
 */
private $model;

/**
 * Many models for one brand
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Brands",inversedBy="models")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="brandId", referencedColumnName="brandId")
 */
private $brandId;
```

Comment: Just follow the example here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional After fixing your relations, change Model::brandId to Model::brand

Comment: @Cerad. thanks but why would I include ::brand which is the field for the brand name ( like Ford, BMW etc )? It's certainly not driving ( pun intended ) any of the relations.

Comment: Because brand is the brand object.  brandId is merely the unique identifier.  For Doctrine 2 try to think in terms of objects and not database column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid and clean entity mapping should be something like:

Brand.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="brands")
 */
class Brand
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * one brands has many models
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Model", mappedBy="brand")
     */
    private $models;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->models = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

Model.php

```
class Model
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * Many models for one brand
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Brand",inversedBy="models")
     */
    private $brand;
}
```

for clean and easy usage:

```
$brand->getId(); //get id of brand
$brand->getModels(); //get array of Model object, ArrayCollection
$model->getBrand()->getId(); // Get id of related brand of some model 
$model->getBrand()->getName(); //get the name of other propery of related brand
```

Comment: Thanks @rafrsr for all the good pointers concerning the proper way to setup the entity. As a beginner they are certainly greatly appreciated. Nevertheless this did not solve my issue, as I said above, it seems that there's some changes that did not get cleaned from cache and are causing the error. I need to find out how to reinitialize all the entities from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

In your `Brands` model, this annotation should not be present.

```
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="brandId", referencedColumnName="brandId")
```

[`JoinColumn`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#joincolumn) only applies to `ManyToOne` and `OneToOne` fields. This is because in a one to many relationship, there will not be a join column in the table that contains the data for the owning ("one") side of the relationship.

`JoinColumn` is for defining a column on the "many" side that identifies which record on the "one" side owns it, so including it in the `Models` model is okay.

Comment: That is a start. Now clean up the Model entity.

Comment: @Cerad I know the naming's a bit off, but is the relation definition wrong in that entity? I thought that that JoinColumn annotation would translate to "create a brandId column in models that refers to the brandId column in brands". I must be missing something.

Comment: @Don'tPanic, As you said, it should work. I believe that's something else the matter. I've changed some field name and though I did flush the cache, it seems that  something is still hanging there. I need to get back and find a way to reinitialize the entities from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong answer removed...

Bonus tips: Entity classes or better their instances should represent single datasets of a table. So their names should be singular ;)
By chosing not prefixed names for your primary key columns, you can spare some code, because Doctrine can work its magic then.
Also you should not prefix one column with the table name, if you do not prefix all of them.

Comment: Close but not quite.  Does it make any sense to have a reference column on a OneToMany relation? http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: @funcOder. I am quite aware of the need for that field to be primary key. If you go back to my question, the problem is that Symfony is not accepting the instruction. As per the so-called Doctrine magic I have a few not so flattering alternative adjectives.

Comment: @func0der, sorry but why should one join on brandId=modelId. That does not seem to make sense. If you would do a mysql query it would be like INNER JOIN ON ( brands.brandId = models.brandId)

Comment: Yeah, sorry. You are right. Anyway. Recheck your code with the documentation. I think you are using'mappedBy' wronf.

Answer (score 0):

This all ended up being an issue with Doctrine's naming strategy, which I did not know about. See [this article for details](http://elnur.pro/how-to-enable-the-underscore-naming-strategy-for-doctrine-orm-in-symfony)

That strategy was set as default, while I was trying to adapt mysql's underscore naming strategy to PHP's camel case naming strategy. This was causing Symfony not to find the primary and thus the error.

Once I learned about that and with the valuable input I've received with this post, I have refactored the entities as below:

Thank you all.

Brands

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="brands")
 */
class Brands
{
/**
 * @var integer
 * 
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="smallint",length=3,unique=true,options={"unsigned":true})
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * one brands has many models
 * 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Models", mappedBy="brandId")
 */
private $models;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->models = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25)
 */
private $brand;
.......
}
```

Models

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ModelsRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="models")
 */
class Models
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="smallint",length=4,unique=true,options={"unsigned":true})
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25)
 */
private $model;

/**
 * Many models for one brand
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Brands",inversedBy="models")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="brand_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $brandId;

/**
 * Many models for one segment
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Segments", inversedBy="models")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="segment_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $segmentId;
.....
 }
```